How create signature for return type when wrapping complex library func?
I have a problem with creating a return type for the Axum middleware creation function.
Ex.
I have middleware with a signature:
async fn auth_middleware(headers: HeaderMap, request: Request, next: Next) -> Result<Response, StatusCode> 

I want to create a function in my crate that returns ready-to-add middleware for Axum, but I cannot figure out the return type of wrapping fn.
pub fn axum_auth_middleware() -> ??? {
    axum::middleware::from_fn(auth_middleware)
}

I'm pretty new to Rust and I spent an hour to solve this but I gave up.

Tip, give it FromFnLayer<(), (), ()> and see what the compiler tells you. You probably still need to tweak it a bit, but that should get you 80% there.

I have checked that already, IDE proposes something like this:
FromFnLayer<fn(HeaderMap, Request, Next) -> impl Future<Output=Result<Response, StatusCode>> + Sized { auth_middleware }, (), _>
But it doesn't compile unknown auth_middleware as well as unknown type cannot be defined in the signature.

Perhaps it'd be easier if you returned impl Layer<S>? Either way it seems like your function should be generic over a service and request, something like fn axum_auth_middleware<S, Request>() -> impl Layer<S> where S: Service<Request> { ... }

{ auth_middleware } isn't a valid part of a type, you must remove it.

This would be relatively easy using the unstable feature tait. Just because I made it, I will share an extremely annoying workaround (it doesn't work on playground, but it is easy to share that way): https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3c7a3c211bc8b8c0c17851b7c7c27099

Probably the best way is to define a dummy Fn trait (MyFn) where Output can be named and then specify the return type as a FromFnLayer where the function is impl MyFn<..., Output: Future + ...> + ...:
use axum::body::Body;
use axum::extract::Request;
use axum::middleware::FromFnLayer;
use axum::middleware::Next;
use axum::response::Response;
use axum::Router;
use http::header::HeaderMap;
use http::status::StatusCode;
use std::future::Future;

async fn auth_middleware(
    headers: HeaderMap,
    request: Request,
    next: Next,
) -> Result<Response, StatusCode> {
    todo!();
}

pub trait MyFn<A, B, C>: Fn(A, B, C) -> <Self as MyFn<A, B, C>>::Output {
    type Output;
}

impl<F, A, B, C, Out> MyFn<A, B, C> for F
where
    F: Fn(A, B, C) -> Out,
{
    type Output = Out;
}

pub fn axum_auth_middleware() -> FromFnLayer<
    impl MyFn<
            HeaderMap,
            http::Request<Body>,
            Next,
            Output: Future<Output = Result<Response<Body>, StatusCode>> + Send + 'static,
        > + Clone
        + Copy
        + Send
        + Sync
        + 'static,
    (),
    (HeaderMap, http::Request<Body>),
> {
    axum::middleware::from_fn(auth_middleware)
}

fn main() {
    let app = Router::<()>::new().route_layer(axum_auth_middleware());
}


Thank you it's working but I have to say, sometimes I'm terrified of how hard is to achieve relatively simple things in Rust.
